# GraphHopper finding point in route

Tags: routes, graphhopper

Given a route between point A and B, starting at time T0, being travelled at constant velocity. Something like the image below:

[image: Sample Route]

Does anybody knows if GraphHopper (or something similar) can say exactly (lat, lon) where in between these two points the traveller will be at time T0+x, where 'X' is some positive amount of time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the GPX result which includes a time for every point. Or use the embedded mode where you could find out such details more easily and a lot more efficient or you could even calculate [isochrones](https://github.com/graphhopper/directions-api/blob/master/README.md#isochrone-api) etc.

Comment: Using the GPX export could be a good solution, but for some reason, not all route export brings the times associated. So I can't depend on this feature. As soon I come up with a solution, I will answer my own question :)

Comment: What do you mean with that - this would be a bug. And again, using the lower level API where you can access the algorithms directly (and easily) you'll have all the info you need